# Installing Scalpel-2.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.10

Im trying to install the latest version of Scalpel from https://github.com/machn1k/Scalpel-2.0. The normal Ubuntu install "sudo apt-get install scalpel" doesnt give me the latest version, so Im trying to get the latest version.

I have fixed the issue, i just missed libtre-dev.

**How to install Scalpel-2.0:**

First install Build Essential and Libtre-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential 
sudo apt-get install libtre-dev
```

Now install Scalpel:

```
git clone https://github.com/machn1k/Scalpel-2.0.git 
cd Scalpel-2.0/ 
./configure 
make
```

Comment: `./configure` doesn't just need to be run - it needs to be run *successfully* in order to generate a Makefile for your system. You will need to look at its output and/or log (`config.log`) to figure out why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I see that I need libtre and libtre-dev.

Answer (score 2):

Just had to run this before installing:

```
sudo apt-get install libtre-dev
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep scalpel` will be useful too.